# 'already added' error trying to build apk: how to identify duplicate dependencies?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, dependency-management

(apologies for any formatting issues, SO's parsing logic is questionable at best and I did what I was forced to do so I could submit this question)

So my app runs fine, but when I try to generate a signed apk, I get 10 errors, all very similar.

```
     Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
already added: Lcom/google/common/base/FinalizableReference;
     Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
already added: Lcom/google/common/base/FinalizableReferenceQueue;
     Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
already added: 
Lcom/google/common/base/FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader;
     (SNIP!)  errors end with this:
     Error:Execution failed for task 
':newAppVariable:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
     > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 Translation has been interrupted
```

From reading SO, I gather I have duplicated dependencies somehow.  Here is my top-level gradle (including changes from Eyad's suggestion below):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

and here is my module-level gradle (again, this is v 2.0 which includes Eyad's recommended changes below):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mogl"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }



    lintOptions {
        disable 'ValidFragment'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    api files('libs/client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I ran `gradlew -q dependencies myappname:dependencies  > gradlew.txt`

and got a lot of output I don't understand.  Which section should I care about?  I'm guessing that since my problem only surfaces when I'm trying to build a signed APK for release that I should care about the release section.  I tried to paste it in this post, but SO thinks it's improperly formatted code instead of the text output which it is, so I have to link to it:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e98adfd44e7aa9f15fe6e50539e42a29

Let's see if I can paste it in as an edit:

```
releaseRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: release
+--- org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0
|    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0
|    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
+--- com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 26.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps-license:11.8.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus-license:11.8.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid-license:11.8.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm-license:11.8.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-license:11.8.0
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.5.0
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1
|    |    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.1
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.1
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.7
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.1
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1 (*)
|    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.1
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0
          +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
          +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
          |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:11.8.0
          +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.8.0
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.8.0
          |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
          |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
          |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
          |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:11.8.0
          |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
          |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:11.8.0
          \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:11.8.0
```

So if my problem is duplicated dependencies, and if I'm supposed to look in the "release" section, I don't understand how to identify them.  For example, look towards the top of the dep tree at the support-v4 library, it looks to me as though it alone has 4 or 5 duplicated dependencies on the support compat library.

But that can't be a problem, can it?  It's google's latest support library, and it seems likely that it's properly constructed, instead of coming from the factory with 4 or so mistakes that will prevent many thousands of developers from building their APKs.  So I believe I don't know what I'm looking for, and I'm hoping you can help me.

I tried using an exclude group to eliminate the support compat dependency of the customtabs library I'm using.  (Sorry I can't post that; the parser again), but it kicked up errors during the gradle sync, so I removed the exclude group, and I'm back to square 1, with no idea how to approach this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you add Fabric using its Android Studio plugin? or manually?

Comment: Eyad - I added Fabric manually, according to their docs (https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install), but then changed away from their recommended "1.+" to specifying their latest version explicitly, because of a warning in Android Studio.
Why do you ask -- have you seen Fabric cause my problem in the past?

Comment: You can ignore this warning, it happens on all libraries but never caused any real issue. Anyway please check my answer below and see if it helps you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric Crashlytics should only be added in module gradle file and shouldn't be in the top level gradle file. If you added Fabric crashlytics using its Android Studio plugin (Which is recommended and better than adding it manually) you will see that it does add it only to the module gradle file. The correct implementation of Fabric crashlytics is something like the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    //Other gradle dependencies here
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: I'll try that.  I am now confused by their docs, as under your interpretation it seems to ask me to include their maven repository twice in the same file, once nested in the buildscript section, and once outside of it.  That seemed...unlikely... to me, so I assumed they were talking about the two different gradle files, not the same one.   But who knows, at this point I'm grateful to have anything that might work.

Comment: Haha it's confusing as it is, but it never caused me any problem before though I've used Fabric crashlytics in more than 6 apps, if you want to make sure everything is correct, remove anything related to Fabric in your code then add the plugin to your Android Studio, login then let Fabric add the crashlytics kit by itself, hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: So trying it as you recommended didn't change anything -- when building the signed apk, the errors are exactly the same.  I expected that, because the dep tree seems to say that Crashlytics doesn't have any google/android deps, and the error messages are all about google stuff.  Many thanks for the suggestion, nonetheless!